# how can i update sound and display from my activity

Tags: android, settings

I used the following code to have the sound and display activity .

Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        viewIntent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS);
        startActivityForResult(viewIntent,1);

Now i need to edit the sound and display settings and to save the updated settings . 
Please assist me for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That code should open the systems settings screens, they should do all the work for you. No need to update the settings yourself.